# How to share a ViewModelProvider.Factory instance between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, dependency-injection, android-lifecycle

I have a ViewModelProvider.Factory instance that is responsible for instantiating ViewModels and injecting repositories into the ViewModels.

This works well for Fragments as I simply supply my custom Fragment factory with the ViewModel factory:

```kotlin
this.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = MyFragmentFactory(myViewModelFactory)
```

The fragment factory injects the ViewModel factory into the Fragments when instantiating them. The Fragments can then access the ViewModels through:

```kotlin
mapViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, myViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

However, I want to launch a new **Activity** that will also require access to the same ViewModel factory.

Can I share my ViewModelProvider.Factory instance across **Activities** without using a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Common class concept.** Make a common class and a public static variable of your required Datatype and store values there and when you need to access just use Common.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME;

```
Public class Common{
  public static REQUIRED_DATATYPE variableName;
  }
```

store the value which you need to access in another activity as
`Common.variableName = YOUR_VALUE;`
and when you need to use just type `Common.variableName`

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the question asked for a method that would avoid using global variables.

Comment: Then you can use sharedViewModel

Comment: As far as I can tell, this still requires a global variable. I have been looking more into this and it seems there is no way to avoid having some global variables when sharing non-trivial data between activities.

Comment: Use bundle to share data